# Ruby parsing tagged string from stanford core nlp into hash

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, hash, stanford-nlp

I use Stanford CoreNLP to parse basic dependencies in (french or english) sentences. It gives me string results like this:

> "(ROOT  (SENT    (NP (DET Ce) (NC magasin))    (VN (V est))    (AP (ADJ pourri))    (COORD (CC mais)      (Sint        (NP (DET les) (ADJ vendeuses))        (VN (V sont))        (AP (ADJ géniales))))    (PUNC !)))"

Now I need this results to be parsed in ruby hash or struct, json or whatever easy to manipulate.

For example in a hash:

```
{'ROOT'=>{'SENT'=>{'NP'=>{'DET'=>'Ce'},'NC'=>'Magasin'}etc...}}
```

I tried several ways to do it but no success.
Could you give me advices or example to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried? We may be able to fix any issue(s) with what you have tried.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. We need to see evidence of your effort toward solving the problem. You say you tried several ways, so summarize that code to its bare minimum and show it to us, otherwise it looks like you're asking us to write code for you which isn't how Stack Overflow works. I'd also recommend reading "[mcve]" since you're having problems with the code. Have you searched for "ruby corenlp" and tried any of those results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really simple parser implementation. `tokenize` splits the string into its parts, `parse` groups the tokens into expressions and feeds them to `hasherize`, which turns them into a tree.

```
def tokenize(str)
  str.split(/\s+|([()])/).reject(&:empty?)
end

def hasherize(tokens)
  tokens, hsh = tokens.dup, {}

  while expr = tokens.shift
    _, key, val = expr

    if val
      hsh[key] = val
    elsif key
      tokens, hsh[key] = hasherize(tokens)
    else break
    end
  end

  [ tokens, hsh ]
end


def parse(str)
  tokens = tokenize(str)
    .slice_when {|left,right| left == ")" || right == "(" }
  hasherize(tokens.to_a)[1]
end

str = "(ROOT (SENT (NP (DET Ce) (NC magasin)) (VN (V est)) (AP (ADJ pourri)) (COORD (CC mais) (Sint (NP (DET les) (ADJ vendeuses)) (VN (V sont)) (AP (ADJ géniales)))) (PUNC !)))"
p parse(str)
# => { "ROOT" => {
#        "SENT" => {
#          "NP" => { "DET" => "Ce", "NC" => "magasin" },
#          "VN" => { "V" => "est" },
#          "AP" => { "ADJ" => "pourri" },
#          "COORD" => {
#            "CC" => "mais",
#            "Sint" => {
#              "NP" => { "DET" => "les", "ADJ" => "vendeuses" },
#              "VN" => { "V" => "sont" },
#              "AP" => { "ADJ" => "géniales" }
#            }
#          },
#          "PUNC" => "!"
#        }
#      }
#    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly.
I dit not try this kind of approach. My first attempts were more about inspecting the string character by character and dealing with the '(' and the ')' but the code began quickly to be unreadable and I knew there was way more quick and safe.

Answer (score 0):

Since the structure is well-formed, we could rely on that and build our own tiny parser. First we change `) (` to commas, then we change parentheses to curlies ans spaces to hashrockets and in the last step we quote everything that is left, considering those to be tokens.

```
eval str.gsub(/\)\s\(/, ',')
        .gsub(/[()\s]/, '(' => '{', ')'=>'}', ' ' => '=>')
        .gsub(/[^{}=> ",]+/) { |m| %Q|"#{m}"| }

#⇒ {"ROOT"=>
#    {"SENT"=>
#      {"NP"=>{"DET"=>"Ce", "NC"=>"magasin"},
#       "VN"=>{"V"=>"est"},
#       "AP"=>{"ADJ"=>"pourri"},
#       "COORD"=>{"CC"=>"mais", 
#                 "Sint"=>{"NP"=>{"DET"=>"les", "ADJ"=>"vendeuses"},
#                          "VN"=>{"V"=>"sont"}, 
#                          "AP"=>{"ADJ"=>"géniales"}}},
#   "PUNC"=>"!"}}}
```

I expect a crowd in comments, downvoting for `eval`, but while you are producing the input, it is absolutely fine.

Safer option would be to `JSON.parse`, though:

```
JSON.parse str.gsub(/\)\s\(/, ',')
              .gsub(/[()\s]/, '(' => '{', ')'=>'}', ' ' => ':')
              .gsub(/[^{}:=> ",]+/) { |m| %Q|"#{m}"| }
```

Comment: I realize this was an edit, but maybe you should consider putting the safer option at the top of your answer. It may also be helpful to explain exactly what this is doing. Quite a few people are unfamiliar with regular expressions.

Comment: @JustinWood Nope, using `JSON` here is semantically incorrect; the `eval` fits the task much better, unless this input comes from an alien source. Only in this case the latter is to be used.

Comment: @mudasobwa In what way is "converting" this string to JSON and parsing it more "semantically incorrect" than converting it to Ruby and parsing it? Both are kludges. Both get the job done. One is safer than the other.

Comment: @Jordan in my opinion, JSON has nothing to do with this transformation. The analogue might be the translation from French to English through Spanish. A redundant link in the chain.